# Tool tip formatter for donut highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, donut-chart

[image: Donut highchart]

I have created donut chart using highcharts.Need to display tooltip as i mentioned in below image.I tried tooltip formatter but no results. Can any one help to fix this issue

Comment: Without code it is hard to help

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure if you have utf8 encoding in your file / meta header.